# Mouse side buttons in python?

Tags: python, button, mouse, hotkeys, extra

I am trying to use my mouse as remote on my laptop and I would like to use side buttons in them. I am coding in python as I have already succeeded doing it with autohotkey. But autohotkey uses too much resources. 
The mouse is Razer Orochi.. It has 7 buttons and a scrollwheel.
I would like to use left side front key for modifier and lbutton, rbutton, mbutton and wheel as secondary... also by pressing both left side buttons I would like to lock the mouse until 4 buttons, all of them on sides are pressed...
**Yet I can't seem to figure out how to read input from side buttons on mouse in python.**

Comment: Depends on the platform, I would think. But it sounds like you are using Windows. I'd guess you'd have to hook into the user32.dll or something.

Comment: Ok... Yes, I'm using win It should work on both 7 and 8...
Sounds like pretty advanced stuff.. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution was made using [PyHook](http://pyhook.sf.net)
Many thanks to Peter Parente.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer, but maybe a set of references to start you out. I don't have experience with Python on Windows, but it looks like these might be helpful:

- there's a set of Windows Extensions for Python: [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).
- Yak created a two-finger scrolling driver by reading the COM in a special way in Python [here](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?t=66785#post=10).

Judging by how Yak got two-finger scrolling in his code, I imagine what you're doing is not so far off? I also think `win32com` would help you out.